# What does IO.sysopen return?

Tags: ruby, io

Could somebody explain I/O to me? From everything I'm gathering, it can be summed up, abstractly, as the way computers interact with humans and vice versa. The I/O channel, or the "how", can run the gamut depending on external devices and/or internal OS management.

So what does the IO class in Ruby do? And how is it different from that of Java or C?

And take this code for instance:

```
x = IO.sysopen("file_name")
p x
```

The return is a `Fixnum` based on the file descriptor. In this case, the "file_name" is a pdf file and return a 7. What does the return object mean?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `sysopen` is a very low-level way of interacting with the system.  For normal input and output in Ruby, you should use `File.open` instead.

The number returned by `sysopen` is called a "file descriptor".  It's essentially an index into an array, but not a Ruby array; it lives inside the part of a process's memory which is maintained by the operating system.  The first file descriptor, number 0, is called "standard input".  Input calls will read from this input stream by default.  The second, 1, is called "standard output"; output calls send their output there by default.  And the third, 2, is called "standard error", which is where error messages go.  All three of those are opened by the operating system before Ruby even starts.  Normally they're all tied to the terminal, but you can change that with shell redirection.

As a general rule, when you open an extra file, the first one you open will get file descriptor 3, the next 4, and so on.  So if you get a 7 back, that just means that Ruby has opened 4 other files by the time it gets to your code.  And that's all it means.  You can't tell anything else about an open file just based on the number.  You have to hand that number off to a system call which can go look at the file descriptor array to see what's up.

But in Ruby, you usually have no reason to know or care about file descriptor numbers.  You deal with instances of the `IO` class (and its subclasses like `File` for specific types of I/O). You call methods on the `IO` objects, and they handle the details of the system calls for you.    The object referred to by the predefined constant `STDIN` (which is also the initial value of the global variable `$stdin`) knows that its file descriptor is 0, so you don't have to know that.

Comment: Nice answer. Yes, there is seldom a reason to go below the `open` level. That's usually considered a major advantage of Ruby and other scripting languages.